# Redirecting old domain with present projects to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, file, redirect, dns, hosting

We're planning to buy a new domain name which is, sample2.com (not real name), but the old one, which is sample1.com (not real name), has projects that are currently running. I have 2 quick options:

- Use 301 Redirect in my htaccess
- Edit all my webfile content/links from sample1.com to sample2.com, for exmaple: sample1.com/images/image1.jpg redirected to sample2.com/images/image1.jpg

Would my current projects be affected? For example, I have an EDM blast that's currently running, the materials are stored on sample1.com. If I bought a new domain and if for example I used 301 direct, would the materials on the EDM still be shown?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: How should we answer that? We know next to nothing about your setup...

Comment: I'm not sure if my files would be affected or not. We'll keep our old domain and let it expire. If I use redirect, does it apply automatically to our already released materials?

Comment: What does that mean? How can a domain name "get applied to material"? If your whatever-you-have makes requests to the old domain name then those would get redirected, sure. If your whatever-you-have gets along with that, then all is fine, if  it does not, then it is not fine. But _we_ certainly cannot tell you how _your_ whatever-you-haves behave...

Comment: Ok, I was confused. Sorry. What I meant was the 1st option that was given to is to use the option to redirect, then the URL lines on my live materials would change = "sample1.com/page1.html" line would become "sample2.com/page1,html", am I right on this?

Another concern is we have EDMs that were already blasted and the assets on those EDMs were housed on our hosting with the old domain. Another option that was given to us is to edit the code lines manually, meaning "sample1.com" should be changed to "sample2.com" code line.

Comment: So what I mean by affected is that, if we follow these steps, would the content on our already blasted EDMs be still viewable to those who we sent it to?

Comment: A redirection rule does not change a line anywhere. Such a rule does not magically modify other things. It operates on incoming requests and _might_ redirect them to other URLs if it gets applied. If anything you created previously makes requests to the old domain, then that domain still has to be active. If in there your redirection rule applies, then that request will get redirected. What happens if you do that, again, is nothing we can say, since only you know what you have created and how that works. We have no idea about that, so we cannot give you any absolution as you apparently hope.

Comment: Ok, I understand that now. Thank you! :)